# Test inner httpClient via WebApplicationFactory

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core

Well, I know this is a bit of a tricky case. I have an ASP.NET Core site backend (`site`) that communicates with another system (`facade`) via http.

But not with `HttpClient` but with clients that `facade` provides with `HttpClient` underneath.

Constructors of these clients look like this

```
public class OrdersClient : IOrdersClient
{
    private HttpClient _client;

    public OrdersClient(IEndpoint endpoint, HttpClient client) 
    { ... }
}
```

And registration looks like this

```
services
    .AddHttpClient("facade-client")
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<CorrelationIdDelegatingHandler>()
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<HttpErrorDelegatingHandler>()
    .AddTypedClient<IOrdersClient>((endpoint, client) => new OrdersClient(endpoint, client));
```

And configuration contains (it's important!)

```
app.UseCorrelationId(new CorrelationIdOptions());
```

N.B. What `endpoint` is for in this case is not important.

Ok. So I want to test my `site` with brand new cool `WebApplicationFactory`. I create it and get a client to the `site` as described in the docs. For some tests I just mock clients to `facade` like

```
public TestOrdersClient: IOrdersClient
{
}
```

and test my logic without `facade`.

**Getting to the point.** I want to test handlers that decorates my `HttpClient` to `facade`.

How I want to test handlers: I register fake PrimaryHttpMessageHandler so it will imitate answers from `facade` in my `WebApplicationFactory`. And I added some `ImitationClient` that used registered `HttpClient`.

```
services
    .AddHttpClient("facade-client")
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpMessageHandlerFake())
    .AddTypedClient<ImitationClient>();
```

**And here I am in trouble.**
In my test a get `ImitationClient` from factory and try to call some method that calls `HttpClient` inside.

```
var factory = new SiteWebApplicationFactory();
var client = factory.CreateDefaultClient();

var imitationClient =factory.Server.Host.Services.GetService<ImitationClient>();
await imitationClient.GetData();
```

And here I get `System.NullReferenceException` because of this handler:

```
public class CorrelationIdDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly ICorrelationContextAccessor _correlationAccessor;

    public CorrelationIdDelegatingHandler(ICorrelationContextAccessor correlationAccessor)
    {
        _correlationAccessor = correlationAccessor;
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.Headers.Add(
            _correlationAccessor.CorrelationContext.Header,
            _correlationAccessor.CorrelationContext.CorrelationId);

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Correlation Id assigned to incoming request to `site` and then forwarded to requests from `site` to `facade`. But when I test only client to `facade` I don't have incoming request, don't have CorrelationContext and fail.

**Finally my question is how to correctly write test for inner `httpClient` with `WebApplicationFactory`.** I know my description is rather confusing, I apologize for that. I am ready to answer any questions on the code and architecture of our project. Thank you!

Comment: First, `TestOrdersClient` is a **stub**, not a **mock**. You create mocks with moq framework by setting the mock up and set conditions and what value to return and validations if the method has been called in the first place and how often. A stuck is a dummy implementation of an interface or abstract class or any other class with virtual methods that can be overridden.

Comment: Second: What kind of tests are you looking for? Unit, Integration or acceptance tests? Your question on that isn't clear, since you use mocks (common for unit tests, testing a unit w/o external dependencies/mocked dependencies), hard dependencies (integration test, testing multiple components with real implementations) and dependency injection/IoC container setups which you usually do in acceptance tests (full application start and doing black box tests against it where only input and output are controlled to be correct)

Comment: @Tseng I can confuse definitions of mock and stub but I hope the point is clear. What I want to test is that all my handlers that I registered in `Setup` work properly. Maybe I wrote too much extra information about mocks.